# PHP regex sytax with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

PHP REGEX is a weakness of mine, but still I manage to get some things done with online tools.  Consider the following:

A subject string which generally follows this pattern:  1551 UTC 04 June 2012

I want to extract the "04" and assign it to the $day variable using below:

```
$day = preg_replace("/^([0-9]{4})\s([A-Z]{3})\s([0-9]{2})\s([A-Za-z]{3,})\s([0-9]{4})$/", "$3", $weather['date']);
```

This works on the following website:  http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/Test_Regular_Expression_Search_Replace.php

but I can't get it to work in my script... $day would equal the whole subject string.

Comment: Have you tried `$day = date('d', strtotime($weather['date']));`

Comment: I just tested it myself, it works perfectly; you must be doing something else wrong (what happens when you var_dump() `$weather['data']`?)

Comment: @randy Sure did, that specifically returns a 01... I don't think the format of $weather['date'] is acceptable for strtotime() to work.  I'm actually trying to extract the different parts of $weather['date'] to create a string which strtotime() can use.

Comment: @Jeroen Results of var_dump($weather['data']): `
string(38) "1551 UTC 04 June 2012 "`

Comment: It works perfectly for me as well. did you `var_dump` $weather['data'] immediately before the line of code above?

Comment: Interesting, `php -r "echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('1551 UTC 04 June 2012'));"` outputs `2012-06-04 08:51:00` on my machine. PHP 5.3.9 from ZendServer CE. Same for a Linux machine running 5.4.3. Do you have `date.timezone` set in your php.ini file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your `var_dump()` is `string(38) "1551 UTC 04 June 2012 "`. It has 38 chars while it should be only 21. So it looks like there are multiple whitespaces in the string.

Try to `trim()` your input string and replace `\s` with `\s+` to support multiple whitespaces:

```
$day = preg_replace("/^([0-9]{4})\s+([A-Z]{3})\s+([0-9]{2})\s+([A-Za-z]{3,})\s+([0-9]{4})$/", "$3", trim($weather['date']));
```

Comment: I think you're on to something.  After using the above, still not working, but I managed to get it down to 31 chars... (with the "+" quantifier attached to the whitespace "\s"

Comment: Using your logic, I was able to get it working.  Instead of the whitespace symbol I replaced it with the period (.) meta-character.  I'm happy this works now, but it leaves another question, what other characters are being added that I can't see?

Comment: Well, it looks they are non-whitespace but unprinted characters. Maybe `ESC`, `DEL`, `NULL`, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

you say preg_replace, but I think you want to use preg_match(). Is that correct that you don't want to replace the "04" but you just want to put it into a the variable $day? If so use preg_match(). In your description you say you want to capture only the "04" part, but your regex has many capture groups (anything within "()" is a capture group and will be returned in the array you give to preg_match).

Comment: You're absolutely right, but the way he's using preg_replace() **should** work; using preg_match wont fix his problem

Comment: Agreed it should work, but `preg_match` would immediately return all relevant parts.

Comment: Technically, `preg_match` returns int or false.

Comment: I'll try preg_match... You're correct I don't really want to replace the string, just extract parts.  However, as Jeroen said, I'm confused why this doesn't work, and it makes me wonder if the same pattern will actually work.  I'll try it out.